# SQL - how to update a column with each row value incremented by 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, auto-increment, row-number

For the selected rows in a column, how to update each row sequentially from the beginning to the end, with each row value incremented by 1 (or certain number). I know this can be done in excel in few seconds but I could figure out how to achieve in SQL server. For instance:

customer id is NULL now
update customer id with every row incremented by 1 (i.e. first row = 1, second row = 2, .....nth row = n)

```
ship-to party   customer id 
0002018092      NULL
0002008127      NULL
0002000129      NULL
0002031592      NULL
0002034232      NULL
```

desired output

```
ship-to party   customer id
0002018092      1
0002008127      2
0002000129      3
0002031592      4
0002034232      5
```

Also, for the selected rows in a column, how to update each row with the row number? I know there is a row_number() function but didn't succeed in producing the desired result. for instance

column A is NULL now
update Column A with every row incremented by 1 (i.e. first row = row number 1, second row = row number 2, .....nth row = row number n)

Any demonstration would be very helpful.thkans

Comment: You do realize that updating the row number to each row is very depending on the order by that is used. If you dont specify an order by there is  no guarantee the row number will be put into the rows you expect

Answer (score 3):

example : suppose I want to add a value to each value in column `SomeIntField` in table `tblUser`

there are 2 ways of doing this easy

first: this just adds value 1 to each column SomeIntField

```
update tblUser set SomeIntField = SomeIntField + 1
```

second : this adds an incrementing value, the first row gets +1, second gets +2, and so on...

```
declare @number int = 0

update tblUser
set    @number = @number + 1,    
       SomeIntField = isnull(SomeIntField, 0) + @Number
```

**EDIT: based on your last comment this might be what you want**

```
declare @table table (shiptoparty varchar(50), customer_id int)

insert into @Table (shiptoparty, customer_id)
values ('0002018092', NULL), ('0002008127', NULL), ('0002000129', NULL), ('0002031592', NULL), ('0002034232', NULL)

declare @number int = 0

update @table
set    @number = @number + 1,    
       customer_id = isnull(customer_id, 0) + @Number

select * from @table
```

The result of this is :

```
shiptoparty | customer_id   
----------- | -----------   
0002018092  | 1 
0002008127  | 2 
0002000129  | 3 
0002031592  | 4 
0002034232  | 5
```

Comment: the second one does not give me the desired result. my column is still null after running the query codes.

Comment: If you give me some sample data and table layout than I can help you. It is not clear from your question what exact you want

Comment: Also add your desired result so we can know exact what you want

Comment: I edited the second solution, have not tested yet. Just give it a try

Comment: Without sample data (you still did not provide any) I can only guess what exact it is you want

Comment: hello, things are getting complicated here. actually I just want to add a unique id number in a new column corresponding to each of the selected rows, in order like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....I can do it in few seconds in excel but want to know how to do it in SQL

Comment: explain better what you want. Do you want to store this values in the table, or do you just want too see the values on your display ? What do you mean by selected rows ? Not all rows from your table ? Please explain better what exact you want. The best way to do this is to edit your question and add the following: 1. sample data in a table style, 2 expected result again in table style

Comment: I updated my answer, it does what you described, unless i do not understand you correct off course

Comment: thank you very much. it works good. Also, instead of generating the sequential unique id, how to retrieve the corresponding row number as the unique id to represent each customer id?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a self referencing variable, use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [Your Incrementing Column],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Columns to Order By]) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET [Your Incrementing Column] = RN;
```

Edit: To prove a point that **ALL** rows will be updated:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (String varchar(50),
                      IncrementingInt int);

INSERT INTO #Sample (String)
VALUES ('sdkfjasdf'),
       ('dfydsfdfg'), 
       ('sdfgsdfg45yfg'),
       ('dfgf54d'),
       ('dsft43tdc'),
       ('f6gytrntrfu7m45'),
       ('5d6f45wgby54'),
       ('g34h636j'),
       ('jw'),
       ('h6nw54m'),
       ('g54j747jm5e5f4w5gsft'),
       ('ns67mw54mk8o7hr'),
       ('h45j4w5h4');

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT IncrementingInt,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY String) AS RN
    FROM #Sample)
UPDATE CTE
SET IncrementingInt = RN;

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

DROP TABLE #Sample;
GO
```

Comment: I think this does not adds a value to the first row

Comment: *Think*? Clearly you haven't tried. ;) `ROW_NUMBER()` will never return `NULL`. If some records aren't being assigned values, it would be because you've filtered your results either within the `CTE` or the `UPDATE`.

Comment: you are overwriting the value in column IncrementingInt, what if there already are values in that column ? I am not sure if the OP wants an empty column filled with values or increment an column with existing values. Your solution works perfect for the first case but not for the second. That is what I meant

Comment: @GuidoG this is why we need DDL, Sample data, and Expected results (and why I upvoted Jibin's comment on the question :) ).

Comment: On this I fully agree

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

you want to increase values in every row in certain column by 1 (or other nuber), try this:

```
update TABLE_NAME set column_to_increase = column_to_increase + 1
```

Second problem:

you want to get row number for only certain rows. Solution: first create column holding all row numbers, then get the rows:

```
select * from (
    select column1, column2, ..., columnN, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as [rn] from MY_TABLE
) where *condition*
```

FYI: `select null` in `over` clause does exactly nothing, it's just there, because window functions (such as `row_number`) have to have `over` clause and some of them require `order by`.

Comment: the first one does not give me the desired result. my column is still null after running the query codes.

Comment: You didn't mention that. What should be the value of null after incrementing it? Should it be treated as zero,so after update is one?

Answer (score 1):

To update each row with row number

Try below

```
CREATE TABLE tmp(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Value INT)

INSERT INTO tmp(value) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

UPDATE T
SET
T.Value = B.RowNo
FROM tmp AS T 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowNo FROM tmp)AS B
ON T.Id = B.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think very complex. Try the simple method given below

```
alter table table_name drop column customer_id
go
alter table table_name add id customer_id IDENTITY(1,1)
go
```