# is there Simple row Reorder method for non primary key columns vb.net

Tags: vb.net

this is my first message to stack overflow. i am currently writing software for a company and have had issue with datatable ordering on rows. let say i have a model below

```
primary key   number Sorted    some string
   100          1                a string
   101          2                another string
   102          3                after string
   103          4                before string
```

lets say i change the order

```
primary key,   number sorted,    some string,
   100           1               a string
   101           2               another string   
   103           4               before string
   102           3               after string
```

i need to re order the number column. is there a way to do this automatically (some internal mechanism in vb.net) so it gives.

```
primary key,   number sorted,    some string,
   100              1             a string
   101              2             another string   
   103              3             before string
   102              4             after string
```

also if i delete one of the items, i need to reorder the number column as such

```
primary key,   number sorted,    some string,
   100              1             a string
   103              3             before string
   102              4             after string
```

becomes

```
primary key,   number sorted,    some string,
   100               1            a string
   103               2            before string
   102               3            after string
```

is there a mechanism in .net to help with this function or can some direction on what code would be best to solve this issue would be grateful.

Comment: The purpose for a primary key is to provide a unique identifier nothing else (like a sequence).  Using a numeric string as the PK seems like...a bold design decision.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: the primary key is used to identify the string and number, the number itself, will then be run in a sequence by a different section of the code. i need to adjust the order of that sequance.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: i should add that the above is an example of a datatable. the primark key is an integer.

Comment: mssql in vb.net. i am running visual studio 13

Comment: Is this vb.net or c# - please do not mix language tags if they are not relevant

Comment: Okay, is there some reason you can't simply order the rows based on the number when you run your query?

Comment: for the later sections of code i need to the system to run in the order of number but those numbers need to be sequancial 1-5 etc. as values could be added, removed or reordered later the pK is used to identify but the number needs to be ordered and reorder when the table is manipulated or changed.

Comment: So you're saying that the "number" column is an integer index for the rows in the table???

Comment: how the rows are stored is not really something you need to worry about,  You can get the data in any order you want using a SQL ORDER BY clause.

Comment: yes. they are the integer index. they  already have the SQL Order by on the number column. the issue is how do you change the integer order so they are sequential after editing them.

Comment: @user9434389: This answer [SQL - how to update a column with each row value incremented by 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711625/sql-how-to-update-a-column-with-each-row-value-incremented-by-1) explains how to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sort method of a DataView setting it to the column you want to sort by. Your initial DataTable is untouched and you have a new sorted DataTable.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim strSQL As String = "Select * From Coffees Order By [Name]"
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(dt)
Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
dv.Sort = "Roast"
Dim SortedDt As DataTable = dv.ToTable
For Each row As DataRow In SortedDt.Rows
      Debug.Print(row("Name").ToString & "  " & row("Roast").ToString)
Next
```